# Applet Components Not VIsible

Tags: java, applet, awt, null-layout-manager

I am Calling an Applet Class After Login. The form is Visible but the Components are Not Visible what COuld be the Issue; Here is My Class:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package stanacle;


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
*
* @author Stano
*/
public class MenuOption extends JApplet{
Label header, menu, error, user;
TextField option;
Button go;

/**
 * Initialization method that will be called after the applet is loaded
 * into the browser.
 */
public void init() {
    // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy 
    setSize(1024, 768);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    header = new Label();
        menu = new Label();
        error = new Label();
        user = new Label();
        option = new TextField();
        go = new Button("GO");
        header.setBounds(370, 10, 200, 20);
        menu.setBounds(10, 60, 200, 20);
        option.setBounds(150, 60, 200, 20);
        go.setBounds(750, 10, 150, 30);
        error.setBounds(370, 310, 500, 20);
        user.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 20);
        header.setText("MENU OPTION PAGE");
        menu.setText("Enter Menu Option");


        add(header);
        add(menu);
        add(option);
        add(go);
        add(error);
        add(user);
}
// TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods
}
```

The Form is Showing but the Components which Include the TextField, The Labeld and the Button Are Not showing.  What COuld I be Doing Wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you have to call setVisible(true)

Comment: I just ran this with JRE 7 (32 bit) and all of the components were visible.

Comment: @Recursed I ran it Directly and some of the COmponents were isible Except the TextField Area. But When I call it from the other Class, Nothing is Visible

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) And in case you missed it earlier in the answer - ***"don't use NullLayout"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) code lines

```
setSize(1024, 768);
setLayout(null);
setVisible(true);
```

must be last code lines into `public void init() {`, because you show container and then to add `J/Components`

2) if isn't there real reason (OpenGL, CAD / CAM) then use

- `Swing JApplet` rather than prehistoric `AWT Applet`
- [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) instead of AWT Components

3) don't use [NullLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I Moved the Code Lines. Is it Probably the Method Am Using to call the Class MenuOption page = new MenuOption();

Comment: `setSize(1024, 768);` ..must be in the HTML.  ;)